# How to add multiple arrays into a single array

Tags: php

In my foreach loop, I am creating an array for each post I loop through. This array contains various post elements that I want to add to a new array and post back via ajax. I want to create a single array with multiple arrays inside that I can then encode and send. Each array looks like this and I'm looping through about 20 times.

```
 $postdata = array(
  'thumb'=>$thumb,
  'title'=>$title,
 );
```

What Im looking for is this:

```
array(
 array(
    'thumb'=>$thumb,
    'title'=>$title,
 )
 array(
    'thumb'=>$thumb,
    'title'=>$title,
 )
 etc...
)
```

I tried array_merge but this didn't work. I'm guessing its something along the lines of:

```
$postsarray = array();

foreach($posts as $p){
 $array = array('thumb'=>$thumb,'title'=>$title);
 $postsarray[] = $array;
}
```

But that still didn't work. I got an empty array with no arrays inside.

Comment: Your last example is the correct method - but how do `$thumb` and `$title` relate to the individual post which is in `$p`.

Comment: $thumb and $title are defined within the loop. Bit more code in there, trying to keep it simple.

Comment: Your code work https://3v4l.org/Sdlfb

Comment: where do you define $posts?

Comment: If your result is an empty array after the `foreach($posts ` loop, then that means `$posts` is an empty array. Add some debugging code to see what `$posts` contains, and also inside the loop to trace how many times it iterates. Things can clear up if you do some debugging.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, yes $posts was empty. Couldn't see how it could have been until someone suggested it. TG for the stack.